# incorrect path of plugin dir on network

Tags: plugins, htaccess

I am using wordpress 3.5+ and I use it as network.
I read that the plugins I upload are activated for all the sites on that network.
So here is the issue. I uploaded a plugin say `XYZ`. It uploaded properly except for the activation part.

Whenever I activate it, it gives out this warning-

```
Warning: fopen(/home4/koc01002/public_html/wordpress-content-folder/plugins/home4/koc01002/public_html/wordpress-content-folder/plugins/XYZ/abc.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/koc01002/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3508

Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home4/koc01002/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3511

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home4/koc01002/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3514
```

The path seems to get appended to the basepath. I dont get where is issue is.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This happens with _any_ plugin you upload, or just a particular plugin?

Comment: This happens with only this particular plugin

Comment: Ok. So what is the plugin and what is the code where the error occurs?

Comment: The plugin is learndash and it works on another wordpress instances. This wordpress site is running on network so maybe this is the issue. About the error, I am still blank at the point where the error occurs, as you know, it is showing error in the standard wordpress function.php file. Where the error could be, is the question I am asking

Comment: The line numbers refer to [`wp_scheduled_delete`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/functions.php#L3476). Does that narrow it down?

Comment: you are refering to line number 3746, while the line number in error is 3508 which refers to [get_file_data](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/functions.php#L3533) , in my case it was Ln-3508 which refers to this function

Comment: the error seems sensible as the file path is obviously appended to the home path. What is causing this, is the question. It happens with this plugin only. Note that the site is on network so it may also be network plugin issue

Comment: The code you posted has line 3508, 3511, and 3514 in `wp-includes/functions.php` which in `wp_scheduled_delete` in trac. What version of WordPress are you using? Either way though, tracing that line number should suggest some possible point of failure in the plugin.

Comment: I am using wordpress 3.5.1

Comment: Well, find where that plugin used `get_file_data`

Comment: I dont think that it is the problem with the plugin. It works well on localhost, and other sites too. It just not working on this site. There could be a possibility that its .htaccess file may not be properly setup or maybe there is some path issue is there.